# FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

I know this isn't a unique question, but perhaps the manifesting situation is unique. Answers found elsewhere don't match what I believe are my circumstances.

I have a box hosting a few sites and, although there are no functional issues as far as I can tell, I see this message sprinkled throughout my Nginx error logs for almost every site. Everything I read points to a problem with my FastCGI params, specifically `SCRIPT_FILENAME`, but my value seems to be inline with what's recommended:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $request_filename;
```

Am I reading the wrong recommendations? I've also noticed that in some cases, but not *all*, the `host` value in the log is one whose `A` record points to the box, but isn't one that Nginx is listening for.

Any idea what might be going on? Is this error "expected" in the case of a 404, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, that's completely out of line. The `SCRIPT_FILENAME` refers to the path of the file on the filesystem, not the path in the request URI.

Typically it should be something like:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: Oy. I guess I was definitely reading the wrong recommendations, then. I swear that what I read when I set this up was to _avoid_ using `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name`. Nonetheless: changed. I'll keep an eye on things, but thanks for your help.